# Can't update Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk to 15.7.2 in crashing UWP UnitTest App

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, mstest

When creating a new **UWP UnitTest App** it shows only a white screen and crashes after a *test was started using the test explorer*.

I'm investigation this issue and found that I'm not able to update the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk Package to latest version **15.7.2**.

**When installing the Package it shows:**

> Cannot modify an evaluated object originating in an imported file
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets".

I wonder if this issue is related to my issue with the unit test apps being broken.

**VS2017 Version: 15.7.2.**

Comment: I'm seeing this problem too, I have reported it in the Visual Studio Feedback.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Good to hear I'm not alone :-) May you share the link to the feedback post with me?

Comment: @MartinZikmund + are you seeing the UWP UnitTest Apps broken too, or do you only face the package upgrade issue?

Comment: I saw a similar thread, could you please check if help? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/229465/cannot-update-microsoftnettestsdk-1570.html